# create certificate and sign it on puppetserver then delivery to client

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Its possible to create certificate and sign it on puppetserver then delivery to client?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the details depend on which version of Puppet you are using.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I use 6.7.0 on both (server/agent), I use something like that in openvpn, so if I can do something similar with puppet it would be very good...

Comment: For Puppet 6.7.0, you are looking for the command [`puppetserver ca generate`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/puppet_server_ca_cli.html).  The docs are a bit sparse on that, however, and  I haven't time at the moment to write up a full answer.

Comment: no problem thats a good point to start... thanks again :-)

Comment: For all others, those are the steps:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#concept-4386